# custom jQuery function to crossfade fonts

Tags: jquery, html, fadein, fadeout, cross-fade

I need a custom jQuery function that lets me target all text elements with a certain class, say `class="fontfade"`, and cause those elements to *crossfade* from their original font to a new font. I can change font like this

```
$(".one").css("font-family", "Comic Sans MS");
```

and HTML Code is

```
<p class="one">Demonstrate transition.</p>
```

The tricky thing here is *crossfading*. I want a smooth transition from previous font to new font. I mean text with previous font will fadeOut and text with new font will fadeIn. So at some point both text with different font can be seen.

I am trying like this

```
$(".one").fadeOut(3000);
$(".one").css("font-family", "Comic Sans MS");
$(".one").fadeIn(3000);
```

not working..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<p><a href="#" class="one">Demonstrate transition.</a></p>

<script>
    $(document).on('click', '.one' ,function() {
        $(".one").fadeOut(3000);
        $(".one").css("font-family", "Comic Sans MS");
        $(".one").fadeIn(3000);
    });
</script>
```

---

Edit: after re-reading your post and comment, perhaps this is what you're after?

```
<script>
    .old {
        font-family: helvetica;
    }
    .new {
        font-family: comic sans;
    }
    .hide {
        display: none;
    }
</script>


<p><a href="#" class="one">Demonstrate transition.</a></p>
<div class="old">Old Font</div>
<div class="new hide">New Font</div>

<script>
    $(document).on('click', '.one' ,function() {
        $('.old').fadeOut(500);

        $('.new').fadeIn(500, function(){
            $(this).removeClass('hide').css("font-family", "Comic Sans MS");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you,but no. It is same to my problem. I need same content fadeOut with previous font and fadeIn with new font

Comment: that's what this does. did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

I created a copy of the div and its text, duplicated it (both with css positioning) then faded the original out while fading the other in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8zDhQ/3/)

Not sure if this is what you want but it may be a start.

```
HTML:
<div id="holder">
    <div class="one">
        Some Text
    </div>
</div>


CSS:
#holder {
    position:relative;
}
.two {
    font-family: helvetica;
    display: none;
}
.two, .one {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}


JS:
$(function () {
    var text = '<div class="two">' + $(".one").html() + "</div>";  
    $("#holder").append(text);
    $(".one").fadeOut(3000);
    $(".two").fadeIn(3000);
})
```